# Rigid Body Joint Constraints can't hold model together in game engine

Tags: game-engine, physics, constraints

I made a simple model (wanted to mess with physics and python scripting).
[image: Boxy robot]

That's bunch of boxes held together with RigidiBody joint (6dof joints with all limits checked)

Problem - model falls apart in play mode:

[image: Broken model]

It DOES try to adhere to constraints, but after wobbling for a several seconds it eventually collapses, which is really disappointing.

[Here's the file.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ltarj8xvb28hgy/walker.7z?dl=0)

Is there a way to fix that (so it adheres to constraints PROPERLY) or should I try another software?

The idea was to try to make this thing walk using physical forces (exercise/fun, not a serious project)

---

The scene was tested on windows platform, 64bit blender 2.74 on 64bit windows 7.

Comment: it doesn't collapse for me , or I'm missing something ?

Comment: @Chebhou: Which platform, which operating system and which blender version (version number, 64/32 bit?). Also, are you absolutely sure that you're starting game engine ("P" key) and not trying to record animation?

Comment: @sigTerrm Windows 7 32bit  Blender 2.73 and I'm sure I'm starting the game engine   : )

Comment: OK , I have tested it on Blender 2.74.5 and yes it's not stable at all as you said

Comment: @Chebhou: So it is a possible regression in 2.74, then? That's good news (because at least now I know how to fix that). I'll try 2.73 and 2.75

Comment: @Chebhou: Nope. Switching to earlier version didn't work. Tried 2.73, 2.74, 2.75. 32 and 64bit. 2.73-2.74 collapse eventually after wobbling for a while, while 2.75 immediately explodes and starts jumping all over the scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to lack of solution I gave up on trying this experiment in blender.

I also investigated V-Rep as possible alternative only to find out that it has same issue.

In the end it looks like I'll have to do that experiment (when I have time) in unity3d, because PhysX apparently does not have this stability problem.